# "Retriving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {432E4F73-87A8-4732-A98D-85CE5B500AD7} failed due to the following error: 80040154"

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce, publish

I've developed an app which is using the MDMLib.dll which is a library for software that we're using in our company (Base Professional) developed by IBM.

Also, there will be constant updates on the app and since my and my colleagues are using the same network, I've figured that the ClickOnce approach will be the best one here.

Everything was good before we've tried to use the APP from another computer (not mine). We're getting this error message:

[image: code]

All of the machines that we're testing on have this software installed so I guess that is not the issue. It works fine on my computer via both VS and the ClickOnce application.

Previously we were using another app which was using the same library but the app was pretty damn slow and badly written but no one had issues like that (sadly the person who developed the previous app, left the company).

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You're either missing a step to register the COM component as part of the installation - I'm not sure how that works with clickonce though - or if that's not a COM component you've created yourself you depend on a third party component that your colleagues don't have installed. At first glance that GUID belongs to MDMLib, but I can't see definitively what that is (from IBM Infosphere?)

Comment: Yes, we're working with software developed by IBM and for this app, I have to use the MDMLib in order to create and edit specific files but all of the computers here have it installed and should be able to access it?

Comment: Have you confirmed/checked that it is registered correctly on the machine in question?

Comment: I am not exactly sure if I understand your question so my answer is "No" I guess.

Comment: You can use this Serverfault answer to check if the COM component is registered - https://serverfault.com/questions/576831/how-do-i-know-if-a-dll-is-registered